# Windows 8 x64 trying to upgrade to 8.1 and I get a 0X8007002-0X3001A error

Tags: windows-8.1

I've done all the required updates possible and when it comes to upgrading my computer to Windows 8.1 this is the error I get:

> 0X8007002-0X3001A

Can anyone help me with this please? Am I missing a patch or something?

Comment: There are tons of things [you should verify](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/unable-to-update-from-8-to-81-error-0x80070488/aff146b9-8fde-424f-8422-a8ff20b56ee2) yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the various updates are installed, per the below article:

this link may help:  http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-8-1-update-fails-to-install

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)